# Estimating the population parameters using the sample moments

Tags: mathematical-statistics, moments, method-of-moments

I have distribution , which is not normal and highly skewed. I take a sample from that distribution and calculate the first four moments of the sample distribution. The first four moments calculated are Mean, variance, skewness and kurtosis. I did this in python using the stats package

Now i want to estimate the mean, variance , skew and Kurtosis of the population distribution. I know that method of moments can do that, but every where i see are example for estimating the first 2 moments of population. I want the third and fourth moment (skew and kurtosis) of the population distribution as well. I would like to all this in python.

Comment: You have already estimated the mean etc. of the population distribution using the method of moments.  What more do you want to do?

Comment: @jbowman Are you saying that if i have a sample distribution and i calculate the mean, variance, etc on that sample, will that mean, variance will be equal to the population distribution as well ?
May be my question was not clear, i have the moments of sample distribution and now i want to estimate the moments of my population , and I do not have access to the population distribution all i have is the sample distribution.
Sorry I am a beginner in this, please let me know if my question is confusing.

Comment: The moments of the sample distribution *are* the method of moments estimators of those of the population distribution, if you don't know the functional form of the population distribution.

Comment: @jbowman
My understanding is coming from this tutorial
https://web.stanford.edu/class/archive/cs/cs109/cs109.1218/files/student_drive/7.3.pdf
If you look up at the last example in this tutorial ,  a sample is defined as X1,X2 ... Now these samples are from Normal distribution, with two parameters. But if I have a distribution which has 4 parameters , the mean, variance, skew and kurtosis. and the sample X1, X2... is from this distribution with 4 parameters. How do i estimate MOM estimator of vector (which is theta1, theta2, theta3 and theta4) [mean, variance, skew, kurtosis]

Comment: You have done that when you calculated the first four moments of the sample distribution.